# MY ASP .NET Server Controls are not rendering

Tags: asp.net, server, rendering, controls

A web development company developed a website for us using ASP .NET Master pages. on the other end i developed content pages that include server controls such as WebUserControls, TextBoxes, ...ETC.

unfortunately non of my ASP .NET Server controls are rendering and when i looked in the page source i can see  inside HTML output.

any ideas that might help in troubleshooting this problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: @DivyaMV i shared samples of my code, thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Do u place ur server controls inside this tag?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
//ur server controls
</asp:Content>
```